# TimeZone details with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, timezone

Hi
I am trying to fig out a way to get the clients timezone details and store it in the database which will be used to calculate UTC dates later on. So what I need is

1) a way to get the clients timezone infor WITHOUT the user selecting from a list (so might need a javascript)
2) What are the timezone details I would need to store which I can then later on use to calculate UTC dates for that user

Please note the project is based on MVC framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to [detect the timezone using javascript](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/) and here's a [more robust version](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/wiki/Home). Then include it in a hidden field or query string variable so that the server can fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getTimezoneOffset()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getTimezoneOffset.asp) method in javascript.
It returns the time difference between Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) and local time, in minutes.